# Getting a loop to show all the powers of 2 from 2048 until 1, display 2048, 1024, 512,...,1

Tags: loops, if-statement, assembly, mips

Using MIPS, I got code to show using SRL to registers all the powers of 2 starting with 2048 until 1. However, it will only display 1. What I want it to do is show all the powers of 2. So for example, I want it to display 2048, 1024, 512, 258, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1. I would have to probably use a loop or something, but being new to MIPS I don't quite understand how I would get this done. Here is my code so far....

```
li $t1, 2048    #Intialize $t1 to 2048
srl $t1, $t1, 11    #Shift right 11 times
add $a0, $t1, $zero #Load contents of variable i to $a0 
li $v0, 1   #Print integer
syscall
```

I would probably want to run a loop saying like, "if $t1 doesn't equal 1, then display the value of $t1," and have that keep running until $t1 does equal 1, then stop the program right?

Comment: yeah, sounds very close to what would do I ... I would first print value (so "2048" is first output), then shift, then loop as long, as the shifted value is not zero (so also "1" gets to the output). (also you may want to display some newline/space between two values)

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you. I was just curious how I would go about doing that loop?

Comment: Consider right-shifting by 1 instead of 11.  You're done when that produces 0.

Comment: @HansPassant For the loop?

Comment: @KyleWelch well, it sounds trivial if you are experienced, and I'm not sure how to help with that, if you really insist on figuring everything from scratch, then keep looking at available instructions and experimenting with them in simulator (debugger! single-step over code), if you understand their description correctly. If you want some head-start, then keep doing the same, but also keep checking some examples/book/tutorials how others did resolve common problems. There's not much more to tell you, except giving you full solution, and I don't think that would be of much help either?

Comment: @Ped7g I understand, I got it to work. Here is what I did

I set the first line of code to 4096 instead of 2048, that away I can print out the 2048. I made the loop, set SRL to shift right once instead of 11 times. Display the number, and if the $t1 is not equal to 1 yet, do it over using the BNE command.

Comment: yep, sounds fine to me. I would still move the shift after printing, start with 2048 (because would this be external "function", I would probably expect the argument to be the first value) and because `beqz` on MIPS is native instruction, while checking if the register has particular non-zero value is usually done by pseudo-instruction, which gets assembled as couple of native instructions.... none of that is anything major, just some food for thought for you, maybe you should try to make this variant too, to get even more skill and experience.